# Escape quotes within triple-quoted strings

Tags: r, json, escaping

Where quotes withing JSON strings are not escaped but nested in triple-quotes e.g.

```
j0 = '[
  {
      "A" : "no quoted bits"
  },
  {
    "A" : """this contains: "quoted" bits""",
    "B" : "no quoted bits"
  },
  {
    "A" : "no quoted bits",
    "B" : """this contains: "quoted" and "more quoted" bits"""
  }
]'
```

reading into R will error e.g.

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(j0)
#> Error: parse error: after key and value, inside map, I expect ',' or '}'
#>            bits"   },   {     "A" : """this contains: "quoted" bits"""
#>                      (right here) ------^
```

I've cobbled together a hacky workaround

```
escape_triple_quoted = function(j){
  j_split = strsplit(j, '"{3}')[[1]]
  f = seq_along(j_split) %% 2 == 0  # filter
  j_split[f] = gsub('"', '\\\\"', j_split[f])
  paste(j_split, collapse = '"')
}

escape_triple_quoted(j0) |> jsonlite::fromJSON()
#>                              A                                              B
#> 1               no quoted bits                                           <NA>
#> 2 this contains: "quoted" bits                                 no quoted bits
#> 3               no quoted bits this contains: "quoted" and "more quoted" bits
# function for parsing strings where quotes are not escaped but nested inside triple-quotes
```

but it doesn't feel like best practice.  Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one-liner for `escape_triple_quotes` using `gsubfn`. The  `gsubfn` function is like `gsub` except the second argument may be a function which inputs the capture groups of the match and outputs the replacement of the match.  It may be expressed in formula notation as we do here.

```
library(gsubfn)
library(jsonlite)

escape_triple_quoted2 <- function(s) {
  gsubfn('"""(.*?)"""', ~ sprintf('"%s"', gsub('"', '\\\\"', x)), s)
}

j0 |>
  escape_triple_quoted2() |>
  fromJSON()
```

giving

```
                            A                                              B
1               no quoted bits                                           <NA>
2 this contains: "quoted" bits                                 no quoted bits
3               no quoted bits this contains: "quoted" and "more quoted" bits
```

Comment: This looks pretty neat. Note the proto dependency opens up X11/XQuartz though - is this a portable workflow?

Comment: Feels like `gsubfn()` deserves to be a base R function..

Comment: gsubfn runs on all platforms that R runs on if you use a standard build which includes tcltk and that has been the case for a decade.  gsubfn uses the regex engine in tcl by default (it can also use other engines). It does not use tk  or X. proto has no dependencies so it is not related to proto.  I don't have a Mac but things you can try are unsetting DISPLAY or using R directly if you are using a front end to R.